# PHP - MYSQL not returning result within set parameters

Tags: php, mysql

This is the sql code i am running:

```
SELECT * FROM documents WHERE cat=1 OR cat=3 AND date>=2001 AND date<=2003 AND run <90 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,10
```

It should return all entries from cat 1 or cat 3 between dates 2001-2003 where run is less than 90 in a random way with a limit of 10 results.

Problem is its ignoring the date and run parameter, they work if you run everything seperate, but all together like above it only returns 10 random entries from cat 1 and 3 with any date/run..

Any idea why??

Thanks.

Comment: Off topic: use `date BETWEEN 2001 AND 2003` instead of `date>=2001 AND date<=2003`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be a case of needing brackets around the `OR` statements like so;

```
SELECT * FROM documents WHERE (cat=1 OR cat=3) AND date>=2001 AND date<=2003 AND run <90 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,10
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  SELECT *
    FROM documents
   WHERE (cat=1 OR cat=3)
     AND date>=2001 
     AND date<=2003
     AND run <90 
ORDER BY RAND()
   LIMIT 0,10
```